# js object replacing values with input

Tags: javascript

I want to store or save data in js object as follow:

```
var car= {};
car[number] = user_input;
```

giving...

```
car = {1:"Fiat"};
```

But I only want to have up to max three values.

```
car = {1:"Fiat", 2:"Honda"};// two values
car = {1:"Fiat", 2:"Honda", 3:"Ford"}; //three values
```

So, if there is another input after three values are already added, then I want it so that it will replace the first value like below:

```
car = {1:"Nissan", 2:"Honda", 3:"Ford"};
```

Then the second value will be replaced next and so on:

```
car = {1:"Nissan", 2:"Tesla", 3:"Ford"};
```

What would be an elegant way of designing this?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

To clarify the question, the key is id number such as "234" or "5432" or "2342".

For example:

```
car = {1233:"Nissan", 555:"Tesla", 3345:"Ford"};
```

Comment: are you sure about an object, if an array would fit better?

Comment: yeah, it will have to be an object as there will lots of value pairs.

Comment: @steveKim thats no problem for an array either

Comment: Mhmm, I would definitely look into it. =)

Comment: `Lots of value pairs` or only 3 (in the question you have mentioned `max 3 values`)? Is your key always going to be integer?

Comment: Well, it is a multilevel objects and the keys will be a specified number. I will add an example in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**remainder operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) and `number % 3` in the property, if your number will change it's value by 1.

`number % 3` - this will keep your index from `0` up to `2`. So if you enter the `4th` element, it's index will be `4 % 3 === 1`, if you starts from `1`.

```
var car= {};
car[number % 3] = user_input;
```

**Example**

```js
var car= [];
var number = 0;
var input;

while(number < 10){
  input = prompt();
  car[number % 3] = input;
  console.log(car);
  number++;
}
```

With ids you can store them and use the `number` to get the appropriate one.

```
var ids = [234, 4641, 1352];
```

```js
var car= {};
var number = 0;
var input;
var ids = [234, 4641, 1352];

while(number < 10){
  input = prompt();
  car[ids[number % 3]] = input;
  console.log(car);
  number++;
}
```

Comment: @steveKim see. Edited

Comment: Thank you for the great information. Just a quick question. Let say the key is not 0-2 number, but rather an id (such as "234", "4641" or "1352"). So the key is not from 0 to 2, but rather a random number. In this case, how would I apply the same concept?

Comment: Here we choose our indexes from the number. With the id's it must be changed. For every time your id's are different or they stay the same

Comment: @steveKim, if the given keys are necessary, please add this information to the question above.

Comment: Same comment: Why do you need the index count? OP says that the user will input the index number?

Comment: I think I simplified the question too much. I actually got the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) and move the value into the range. Then add one for the one based interval.

```js
var car = {},
    insertCar = function (index) {
        return function (carName) {
            car[index + 1] = carName;
            index++;
            index %= 3;
        }
    }(0);


insertCar('Fiat');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Honda');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Ford');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Nissan');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Tesla');
console.log(car);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With give keys `[234, 4641, 1352]` and round robin

```js
var car = {},
    insertCar = function (index) {
        var keys = [234, 4641, 1352];
        return function (carName) {
            car[keys[index]] = carName;
            index++;
            index %= keys.length;
        }
    }(0);


insertCar('Fiat');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Honda');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Ford');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Nissan');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Tesla');
console.log(car);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With an array, as suggested

```js
var car = [],
    insertCar = function (index) {
        return function (carName) {
            car[index] = carName;
            index++;
            index %= 3;
        }
    }(0);


insertCar('Fiat');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Honda');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Ford');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Nissan');
console.log(car);
insertCar('Tesla');
console.log(car);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why do you need the index count? OP says that the user will input the index number?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee, the op does not know, what to use. a comment shows, that possible an array of keys is used ... but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
var carCount = "Take this as UserInput";
var newValue = "Take the value as Input as well"

if (carCount < 3){
  (car[carCount] = newValue);
}
```

Comment: I upvoted. It's simple but I can see how it can be used. I am not sure who downvoted.

Comment: @steveKim If you liked my answer can you please accept the answer? Thanks